# GCC/LD position-independent code with instruction-relative data access

Tags: gcc, embedded, ld

## Motivation

Suppose I had:

```cpp
int       some_bss_values[8];
int       some_data_values[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int const some_rodata_values[] = {9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};

//Some silly code that shows usage of bss, data, and rodata
int some_function(int x) {
   some_bss_values[x] = some_rodata_values[x];
   return some_data_values[x]++;
}
```

My ultimate goal is to compile this to a binary blob that I could load at runtime (this is an embedded system, so no dynamic linkers or even ELF loaders). Specifically, I want to be able to load this blob, data included, at any address and jump to `some_function`.

## What I tried

I tried writing a simple linker script:

```
SECTIONS {
    .text : {
        *(.text);
    }
    .data : { 
        *(.bss); /*Placed here because I explicitly want the BSS to be part of the image*/
        *(.data); 
    } =0
    .rodata : { *(.rodata); }
}
```

I compiled the example code to an ELF with:

```bash
# Using -g and -O0 so we can have a readable disassembly. I'm actually using
# a cross-compiler but we'll use regular gcc with x86 for the sake of the question

gcc -Wl,-esome_function -o t.elf -fPIC -nostdlib -T my_linker_script.ld -g -O0 my_code.cpp
```

Then I generated an image with:

```bash
objcopy -Obinary -j.text -j.data -j.rodata t.elf t.bin
```

## The problem

The above commands produce a binary blob for me to use, including the explicit zeroes for the BSS, but looking at the disassembly highlights a problem:

```
objdump -sSxC t.elf

...
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00200000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .text         00000053  0000000000000024  0000000000000024  00200024  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .data         00000040  0000000000000080  0000000000000080  00200080  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
...

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000024 <some_function(int)>:
int       some_bss_values[8];
int       some_data_values[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int const some_rodata_values[] = {9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};

//Some silly code that shows usage of bss, data, and rodata
int some_function(int x) {
  24:   55                      push   %rbp
  25:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  28:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   some_bss_values[x] = some_rodata_values[x];
  2b:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  2e:   48 98                   cltq   
  30:   48 8d 14 85 00 00 00    lea    0x0(,%rax,4),%rdx
  37:   00 
  38:   48 8d 05 a1 00 00 00    lea    0xa1(%rip),%rax        # e0 <some_rodata_values>
  3f:   8b 0c 02                mov    (%rdx,%rax,1),%ecx
  42:   48 c7 c0 80 00 00 00    mov    $0x80,%rax
  49:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
  4c:   48 63 d2                movslq %edx,%rdx
  4f:   89 0c 90                mov    %ecx,(%rax,%rdx,4)
   return some_data_values[x]++;
  52:   48 c7 c0 a0 00 00 00    mov    $0xa0,%rax
  59:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
  5c:   48 63 d2                movslq %edx,%rdx
  5f:   8b 04 90                mov    (%rax,%rdx,4),%eax
  62:   8d 70 01                lea    0x1(%rax),%esi
  65:   48 c7 c2 a0 00 00 00    mov    $0xa0,%rdx
  6c:   8b 4d fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%ecx
  6f:   48 63 c9                movslq %ecx,%rcx
  72:   89 34 8a                mov    %esi,(%rdx,%rcx,4)
}
  75:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  76:   c3                      retq
```

Here we see that reading from `rodata` correctly uses instruction-relative addressing. However, it seems to be using a hardcoded address of 0 for the BSS, and a hardcoded address of `0xA0` for the data section.

How can I instruct gcc/ld to use instruction-relative addressing for data in the BSS and `.data` sections?

Comment: What architecture is your embedded system?  You seem to be using x86_64 but I just want to make sure, since it's kind of unusual for a small embedded system to use x86_64.  I would expect ARM or RISC-V or something like that.

Comment: I'm using a custom RISCV cross-compiler. I left it as regular gcc with x86 for easy reproducibility

Comment: The linker may give sections like `.data` and `.bss` special meanings, later used by the CRT. It would seem that the easiest for you would just be to solely use custom sections with the gcc attribute gunk included in the source: `__attribute__((section(".mybss")))` and `__attribute__((section(".mydata")))` with corresponding sections in the linker script.

Comment: Unrelated, why are you compiling C++ source files with gcc?

Comment: I've always done that. I guess `gcc` just switches to `g++` behind the scenes, tbh I've never thought about it

Comment: If I try as you wrote, I get `/usr/bin/ld: t.elf: Not enough room for program headers, try linking with -N`. If I follow this advice, I get PC-relative addressing for all data.